# Customized multiple image selection

Tags: android

I want to create the code in android for "Multiple Image Selection" from gallery from the android device. Already, I refer this url http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery.html.
 But I need customized selection (any type) instead of put the check box on each and every image. could you help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: you can select images when user long press on any image like whatsapp messages

Comment: That also I tried, but sometimes not working. so that I need various type to select images.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement Action Bar Contextual.

Here the official documentation:

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html

Here's an example:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab

Maybe you need Action Bar multiple sample.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need in customized way. Please look this url, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.cinche.cinchegallery. I want like this (in any style but without using the checkbox)